# Access combobox properties inside array of comboboxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I have an array of combo boxes that are dynamically added to a windows form in VB.Net using Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to access the cboBox.list and cboBox.selecteditem properties, and I absolutely can if I use

```
                dim cboList() as ComboBox = {}

                ReDim Preserve cboList(cboList.Count)
                Dim location As New System.Drawing.Point(FieldX, FieldY)

                cboList(cboList.Count - 1) = New ComboBox
                With cboList(cboList.Count - 1)
                    .Name = "cboName"
                    .Location = location
                    .Size = Size
                    .TabIndex = 1
                End With
```

And then to access it I use either

```
     cboList(0).Items
```

or

```
     cboList(0).SelectedIndex
```

Because these are generated from information in the database, where I store their name, X/Y location, etc., and may be added at different times while the program is running, I may not have the same combobox in 0 location each time. I've been trying to find a way to do this:

```
   cbolist("ComboName").Items
```

And have come up dry on the internet. Is there a way to use the combobox name in the array to find the find the proper combobox, and if so, how?

I'm using VB.Net Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a `Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox)` instead of an array:

```
Dim cboDictionary as Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox)
Dim cbo As New ComboBox
With cbo
  '...
End With
cboDictionary.Add(cbo.Name, cbo)
```

Notice by doing so you would also get increased performance, if you have many ComboBoxes, and their number is changing often. This is because `Dictionary` is optimized for this scenario, `lookup`, `add` and `remove` operations in most cases all run in **O(1)** time.

An array does not have `lookup` functionality, so it would require iteration to find an element, and a new array needs to be created to add or remove an element (which you are doing with `ReDim`). In contrast, `Dictionary` does **not** recreate itself every time.

Comment: I'm converting my array over now, how do I use this to access the combobox in the dictionary based on the name?

Comment: Ok scratch that, I figured that out. Thank you for your help. Now I just have another problem I'm trying to figure out...

Comment: @Bigdaddyduergar: You are welcome! TryGetValue is the most efficient way to retrieve a value from the dictionary. If you have another question which fits the format of SO, feel free to ask as a new question.