# Converting control to generic object for looping purposes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops, dictionary, casting

I have several dictionaries set up:

```
Dim DDLs As New Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox)
Dim CBOs As New Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox)
Dim LBLs As New Dictionary(Of String, Label)
Dim TXTs As New Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)
Dim TBXs As New Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)
Dim DTPs As New Dictionary(Of String, DateTimePicker)
Dim NUDs As New Dictionary(Of String, NumericUpDown)
```

Each one of them contains controls that are dynamically added to my windows form. I am able to add everything just fine to each dictionary. I then create an array of dictionaries so that I can, using minimal code, loop through them to add them to the form. Originally, these were all arrays of items, but due to another issue I had, I had to convert them to dictionaries.

Here is the code to add the objects to the form:

```
Public Sub AddFormObjects()
    Dim FormObjects() As Object = {DDLs, CBOs, LBLs, TXTs, TBXs, DTPs, NUDs}

    For Each Obj In FormObjects
        For Each FormObj As KeyValuePair(Of String, Control) In Obj
            Me.Controls.Add(FormObj.Value)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

I'm trying to find what I can use for the `keyvaluepair(of string, XXXXXX)` that will allow me to continue to use this logic, or something similar, to add the items to the form. I don't want to create a giant select case statement.

My thoughts were either to find a generic type that the form can read and add that each of the form objects can be converted to, or find a way to dynamically declare the TValue type based on the tvalue type of the dictionary being accessed in the array.

All of my searches have come up short at this point in time for finding either one.

I'm currently using VB.Net, framework 3.5, in VS2010.

Comment: a class Of T wrapper for those Dictionaries where T = TValue should work.  each class would then perform the AddObjects loop for its own type. instead of directly managing the dictionaries do it thru a managing class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the code for a bit more, I found this to work just fine:

```
    Public Sub AddFormObjects()
        Dim FormObjects() As Object = {DDLs, CBOs, LBLs, TXTs, TBXs, DTPs, NUDs}

        For Each Obj In FormObjects
            For Each FormObj As Object In Obj
                Me.Controls.Add(FormObj.Value)
            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

Casting the dictionary itself as a generic object instead of specifically the items held in the dictionary worked for me. Thank you for your help! It started me thinking down a different path.

Comment: This code is exactly what you already had, just using implicit typing for your FormObj variable.

Comment: Or are you saying that you changed Dim DDLs As New Dictionary(Of String, ComboBox) to Dim DDLs As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)?

Comment: Originally, inside of the loop I was using: For Each FormObj As KeyValuePair(Of String, Control) In Obj. Instead of that, I'm now using For Each FormObj As Object In Obj. So instead of trying to cast each Obj as a keyvaluepair, which is where my issue was coming in at, I switched to casting it as just a regular Object. I did not modify the original dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 0):

All controls inherit from the [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, so any form control can be passed into anything requiring a Control (it's not really being converted, because it already is a Control), like a Dictionary(of String, Control).

You can also check the type of any Control, so if you need to find all TextBoxes you can say

```
For Each control In Me.Controls
    If control.GetType() is GetType(TextBox) Then
        'Set some TextBox specific property
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I think he has them segregated by type so he can set Type-specific properties such as .Min / .Max for a NumericUpDown.  TValue of Control would result in lots of CType statements.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24518178/1070452

Comment: "My thoughts were either to find a generic type that the form can read and add that each of the form objects can be converted to" This is exactly the solution I gave.

Comment: That is correct Plutonix. TXT is a generic textbox, where tbx is set to be multiline textboxes.